# Pop up no displaying properly in mobile

Tags: jquery, html

i am using jquery mobile 1.4.2
I am trying to create pop up dynamically in my page.Its working fine in computer but if i open same page in a mobile its displaying for a second and its going off.
here is my code

### html

```
<button id="yo1">Click</button>
```

### jquery

```
$(document).on('vclick','#yo1',function(){
var message = '<input name="im_user" type="text" class="valores" id="im_user"/><input name="im_password" type="password" class="valores" id="im_password" /><input name="inputAds" type="submit" id="inputAds" value="Ingresar" />',
   popupafterclose = '';
   runtimePopup(message, popupafterclose)


   });
 function runtimePopup(message, popupafterclose) {
  var template = "<div data-role='popup' class='ui-content messagePopup'>" 
  + "<a href='#' data-role='button' data-theme='g' data-icon='delete' data-iconpos='notext' " 
  + " class='ui-btn-right closePopup'>Close</a> <span> " 
  + message + " </span> </div>";

      popupafterclose = popupafterclose ? popupafterclose : function () {};

      $.mobile.activePage.append(template).trigger("create");

     $.mobile.activePage.find(".closePopup").bind("tap", function (e) {
     $.mobile.activePage.find(".messagePopup").popup("close");
     });

    $.mobile.activePage.find(".messagePopup").popup().popup("open").bind({
          popupafterclose: function () {
             $(this).unbind("popupafterclose").remove();
          popupafterclose();
         }
          });
         }
```

link to jsfiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7uh9u/3/). Its not displaying properly only in mobile phones.Working fine in computer.

Comment: You know that since V1.4 you can put the markup of a popup outside of any page right?

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding refresh after create

```
$.mobile.activePage.find(".messagePopup").popup("refresh");
```

after you create the popup.

Comment: @user3350169 target that pop with id or specified class and try the code just $('selector').popup(); or $('selector').popup('refresh');.... also check console for any errors

Comment: its showing error like Error: no such method 'refresh' for popup widget instance